# How can capture the second console window show up of external process and add it to a pictureBox on winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Grads_Scripts
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // ****************** \\

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern long SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, long x, long y, long cx, long cy,
                                               long wFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName,
                                           string lpCommandLine,
                                           IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
                                           IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
                                           bool bInheritHandles,
                                           uint dwCreationFlags,
                                           IntPtr lpEnvironment,
                                           string lpCurrentDirectory,
                                           ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
                                           out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xf020;
        public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xf030;


        public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }

        public struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public uint cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public uint dwX;
            public uint dwY;
            public uint dwXSize;
            public uint dwYSize;
            public uint dwXCountChars;
            public uint dwYCountChars;
            public uint dwFillAttribute;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int length;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public bool bInheritHandle;
        }

        string cmd = "";
        string exepath = @"C:\OpenGrADS\Contents\Cygwin\Versions\2.0.2.oga.2\i686\opengrads.exe";
        private static StringBuilder cmdOutput = null;
        Process cmdProcess;
        StreamWriter cmdStreamWriter;
        string pathDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\settings";
        string settingsFile = "settings.txt";
        StreamWriter w;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button4.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            if (!Directory.Exists(pathDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDir);
            settingsFile = Path.Combine(pathDir, settingsFile);
            if (File.Exists(settingsFile))
                textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(settingsFile);
            button1.Select();
            textBox2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.MySettings;
            if (textBox2.Text != "" && File.Exists(textBox2.Text))
            {
                button4.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                ProcessCommands();
            }
            if (File.Exists(exepath) && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                textBox2.Text = exepath;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.MySettings = textBox2.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                ProcessCommands();
            }
            else
            {
                button4.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void ProcessCommands()
        {
            cmdOutput = new StringBuilder("");
            cmdProcess = new Process();

            cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = textBox2.Text;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdProcess.Start();

            cmdStreamWriter = cmdProcess.StandardInput;
            cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] cmdTextParts = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
            foreach (string item in cmdTextParts)
            {
                cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine(item);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                {
                    if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("GrAD"))
                    {
                        names.Add(process.ProcessName + " " + process.Id + " " + process.MainWindowTitle);
                        if (process.ProcessName == "Xming")
                        {
                            CaptureApplication(process.MainWindowTitle);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = Regex.Replace(cmdOutput.ToString(), @"\e\[(\d+;)*(\d+)?[ABCDHJKfmsu]", "");
            richTextBox1.Text = result;//cmdOutput.ToString();
            richTextBox1.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmdStreamWriter.Close();
            cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
            cmdProcess.Close();
        }

        private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                cmdOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            w = new StreamWriter(settingsFile, false);
            w.Write(textBox1.Text);
            w.Close();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            theDialog.Title = "Open Grads File";
            theDialog.Filter = "EXE files|opengrads.exe";
            theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Text = theDialog.FileName;
                button4.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.MySettings = textBox2.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                ProcessCommands();
            }
        }

        public void CaptureApplication(string _title)
        {
            string _wndcls = "ConsoleWindowClass";
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            CreateProcess(_title, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
            IntPtr _wndConsole = IntPtr.Zero;
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                _wndConsole = FindWindow(_wndcls, _title);
                if (_wndConsole == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                    continue;
                }
                break;

            }    
                IntPtr value = SetParent(_wndConsole, this.pictureBox1.Handle);
                int style = GetWindowLong(_wndConsole, -16);
                style &= -12582913;
                SetWindowLong(_wndConsole, -16, style);
                SendMessage(_wndConsole, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the `button1`, click event the program send commands to console window of `opengrads.exe` that I run in exepath variable.
Once the commands run this `opengrads.exe` open a new process called Xming.
I can in the tray icon this Xming start running. So first I have `opengrads.exe` then it's making Xming to start running.

Now if in the method `CaptureApplication` as title I will put in `button1` click event `opengrads.exe` it will capture the `opengrads.exe` console window and add it to my `form1` `pictureBox1`.

**I want to capture the Xming console window and to add it to `pictureBox1`.**

In `button1` click I did tests and can find the Xming process and get it's id name `mainwindowtitle` tried to send to `CaptureApplication` the "Xming" then "Xming.exe" didn't work tried to send to the method the `MainWindowTitle` but also didn't work.

This is a screenshot of my program on the right you can see the `opengrads.exe` captured in `pictureBox1` on the left is the Xming window I want to capture instead but can't:

[image: My program screenshot]

On the left window that I want to add to `pictureBox1`. I see it's title `GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2` tried to send it to `CaptureApplication` method as title also but it didn't work either.

If it will help you can download the `opengrads.exe` [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opengrads/files/)

Comment: You can redirect the process' standard output stream and capture anything that it outputs via an event on the process instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the process' stardard output stream and capture anything that it outputs to a string.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "myapp.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

proc.WaitForExit();
```

You can then draw the captured string on to your bitmap via standard `Graphics` calls.